# Construct array of values from list of lists with missing values

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I want to construct a list of strings, as such:

```
ideal = ["cheese", "bread", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"]
```

I am given a list of String arrays all containing values.

```
args = [
    ["cheese", "bread", "fire", "stone", "pot"],
    ["cheese", "bread", "pot", "straw"]
    ["cheese", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"]
    ["cheese", "bread", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"]
    ["bread", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"]
]
```

If I create a list of all values within the lists, I can create the above ideal list. However, some values are missing in some of the arrays. I also need to preserve the order in which the labels appeared in the list.

The solution should find the correct order e.g. if one array is `[cheese, fire, pot]` and the next is `[cheese, bread, fire]`, it should deduce that `[cheese, bread, fire, pot]` is the correct sequence.

How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem but I solved it with the following set of steps:

1. Create the 2D list:

```
args = [
    ["cheese", "bread", "fire", "stone", "pot"],
    ["cheese", "bread", "pot", "straw"],
    ["cheese", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"],
    ["cheese", "bread", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"],
    ["bread", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"]
]
```

2. Generate a dictionary containing arrays of strings that appear before other strings:

```
before_dict = {}
for arg in args:
    for i in range(len(arg)):
        if arg[i] not in before_dict:
            before_dict[arg[i]] = []
        for j in arg[:i]:
            if j not in before_dict[arg[i]]:
                before_dict[arg[i]].append(j)
```

This results in:

```
{
    'fire': ['cheese', 'bread'],
    'pot': ['cheese', 'bread', 'fire', 'stone'],
    'bread': ['cheese'],
    'stone': ['cheese', 'bread', 'fire'],
    'cheese': [],
    'straw': ['cheese', 'bread', 'pot', 'fire', 'stone']
}
```

3. As we can see `'cheese'` comes first as it has an empty array (i.e. nothing comes before it), we can add it to the final result and then remove cheese from other arrays, we then repeat to get the final answer:

```
ideal = []
repeating = True
while repeating:
    repeating = False
    for k in before_dict:
        if before_dict[k] == []:
            repeating = True
            ideal.append(k)
            del before_dict[k]
            for k2 in before_dict:
                if k in before_dict[k2]:
                    before_dict[k2].remove(k)
            break
```

This finally results in:

```
['cheese', 'bread', 'fire', 'stone', 'pot', 'straw']
```

The same result is obtained for:

```
args = [
    ["bread", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"],
    ["cheese", "bread", "fire", "stone", "pot"],
    ["cheese", "bread", "pot", "straw"],
    ["cheese", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"],
    ["cheese", "bread", "fire", "stone", "pot", "straw"]
]
```

And provides the result:

```
['cheese', 'bread', 'fire', 'pot']
```

for input:

```
[
    ["cheese", "fire", "pot"],
    ["cheese", "bread", "fire"]
]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't guarantee the correct order. If the last array in the list was first, then cheese would come after straw.

Comment: @nonsequiter Can you add into your question how you generated the correct order then?

Comment: The solution should find the correct order e.g. if one array is [cheese, fire, pot] and the next is [cheese, bread, fire], it should deduce that [cheese, bread, fire, pot] is the correct sequence.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I'll look into this, can you edit that into the question

Comment: Explanation was v helpful too

Comment: @nonsequiter I think giving you just the construction of `before_dict` you could've figured out where to go with it, often finding a way to usefully represent the data is the most difficult part, but I thought a map of each word and the words that came before it was most sensible.